# Taking multiple inputs from user in command prompt with python

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to build a very simplistic port scanner in order to practice with the concept of sockets. The design I have is as following:

```
from socket import *

ip = input("Submit IP to scan:")
start = input("Submit starting port:")
end = input("Submit ending port:")
print("Scanning IP:", ip)
for port in range(int(start),int(end)):
    print("Scanning port:" + str(port) + "..")
    var_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    var_socket.settimeout(3)
    if var_socket.connect_ex((ip,port)) == 0:
        print("port", port, "is open")
    else:
        print("err code:", var_socket.connect_ex((ip,port)))
    var_socket.close()
print("Scanning completed!")
```

This all works pretty well when I run it from a file. Unfortunately I may not always have the luxury to run my scripts from a file, so I'll need to be able to create this script in a command shell. I've made some attempts myself with tips and tricks from the internet, but they all failed in some way.

```
from socket import *    #Press enter. Note that I am in a windows terminal. 

ip = input("enter ip to scan:")\   #Press enter
start = input("enter starting port:")\     #Press enter
```

output:
Syntax error: Invalid syntax

The other solution I found actually worked, but brings some unwanted complexity along the way:

```
from socket import *

ip,start,end = map(int,input().split())   #Press enter
```

This solution allows me to enter 3 values seperated by a space, mapping them to ip, start and end respectively. Of course this will not work unless I design a function that manually transforms the entered ip value into a valid dotted decimal IP address. Does anyone know a better approach to ask for multiple inputs in a shell environment?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) ?

Comment: I'm looking into it. Will let you know if it solves my problem!

Comment: The argparse library does seem useful indeed. It's use, as described in the documentation, is for enhancing flexibility of a program file ran from the command line. I need to write my entire program from within a commandline, without saving it to a file. For my particular problem, I'm afraid this won't be able to help. But thanks anyway for the input (<-pun intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When copying your script, the python interpreter reads your code line by line, which makes it fill your input with the script you are typing.
One solution to avoid that is to read files from a different place (arguments, files, …). Or, you can also load your script in memory, then execute before asking for the inputs:

```py
script = '''
from socket import *

ip = input("Submit IP to scan:")
start = input("Submit starting port:")
end = input("Submit ending port:")
print("Scanning IP:", ip)
for port in range(int(start),int(end)):
    print("Scanning port:" + str(port) + "..")
    var_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    var_socket.settimeout(3)
    if var_socket.connect_ex((ip,port)) == 0:
        print("port", port, "is open")
    else:
        print("err code:", var_socket.connect_ex((ip,port)))
    var_socket.close()
print("Scanning completed!")
''' 
exec(script)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The reason I want to be able to create and execute the script from a shell, is because in some penetration testing setups you don't have access to files, but you can drop into a python shell!